# How can I use bash to show a hierarchy structure?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, sh

I have a csv file like below. The ID is the unique identifier of each employee, and the MANAGERID is the ID of his/her manager.

```
id,managerid,firstname,lastname,dob,address
1,0,John,A,1976-01-01,some where
108,12,Tom,B,1996-01-01,some where
85,12,Jerry,C,1975-01-01,some where
12,1,Winsor,D,1984-01-01,some where
16,85,Smith,H,1977-01-01,some where
100,0,Ray,G,1999-01-01,some where
22,100,Albert,B,1980-01-01,some where
17,22,Robert,J,1980-01-01,some where
21,22,Linda,K,1981-01-01,some where
35,17,Lily,J,1968-01-01,some where
101,0,Sam,A,1995-01-01,some where
105,101,Liz,Z,1988-08-08,earth
```

I want to use a bash command/script to print out the structure, like a tree. The top manager is the root, following by the department manager and the employees of the department. The ID & name of the top manager should also be listed aside the employees.

I dont have a clue how to do this yet.

The expected output should be like this.

```
1:John A(1:John A)
+12:Winsor D(1:John A)
+-85:Jerry C(1:John A)
+--16:Smith H(1:John A)
+-108:Tom B(1:John A)
100:Ray G(100:Ray G)
+22:Albert B(100:Ray G)
+-21:Linda K(100:Ray G)
+-17:Robert J(100:Ray G)
+--35:Lily J(100:Ray G)
101:Sam A(101:Sam A)
+105:Liz Z(101:Sam A)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: First of all, if it is **really** a general CSV file, you need a CSV parser, because you need to understand quotes in fields (which are used if, for instance, a field contains a comma or a newline character). This already suggests that _bash_  is perhaps the second-worst tool for the task (after _sh_, which you you also proposed for the task). Use a language which comes with a CSV parser (Ruby, Perl, Java, ...), then think about an algorithm (i.e. how you would solve the problem with pencil and paper), and finally think about how to implement it.

Comment: SO is not a place where you can find free coders to do your assignments. It's a place where you can find help with your **own** code. So you would probably increase your chances of receiving useful answers if you 1) first tried to solve your problem, 2) come back here with your code and explain what difficulties you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `python` installed, you can try this code. It works in python2 & python3.

tree.py:

```
import sys

class Employee:
  def __init__(self, id, pid, name):
    self.id = id
    self.pid = pid
    self.name = name
    self.level = 0
    self.managerinfo = self.id+": "+self.name

def printlist(rlist): 
  for e in rlist:
    print('+'.ljust(e.level+1,'-')+e.id+":"+e.name+"("+e.managerinfo+")")

def insone(mylist, id, newe):
  idx=0
  for e in mylist:
    idx+=1
    if e.id == id:
      newe.level = e.level+1
      newe.managerinfo = e.managerinfo
      mylist.insert(idx,newe)
      #print('Insertint '+newe.id+':'+newe.name+' after '+e.id+':'+e.name)
      return True
  return False

def sortlist(sorted,unsorted):
  #print("begin:"+str(len(unsorted)))
  if len(unsorted)<=0:
    return
  for u in unsorted:
    if u.pid == '0':
      sorted.append(u)
      unsorted.remove(u)
    else:
      if insone(sorted, u.pid, u):
        unsorted.remove(u)
  #print("end:"+str(len(unsorted)))
  sortlist(sorted,unsorted)

if __name__ == "__main__":

  file1 = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
  Lines = file1.readlines()

  rawlist=[]
  line=0
  for row in Lines:
    line+=1
    if line>1:
      a = row.strip().split(',')
      rawlist.append(Employee(a[0],a[1],a[2]+" "+a[3]))

  sortedlist = []
  sortlist(sortedlist,rawlist)

  printlist(sortedlist)
```

Then run this,

```
[ rquery]$ python tree.py samples/organization.csv
+1:John A(1: John A)
+-12:Winsor D(1: John A)
+--85:Jerry C(1: John A)
+---16:Smith H(1: John A)
+--108:Tom B(1: John A)
+100:Ray G(100: Ray G)
+-22:Albert B(100: Ray G)
+--17:Robert J(100: Ray G)
+---35:Lily J(100: Ray G)
+--21:Linda K(100: Ray G)
+101:Sam A(101: Sam A)
+-105:Liz Z(101: Sam A)
```

**Alternatively, if you can download `rq`, it can complete this task within one command line.**

```
[ rquery]$ ./rq -n -q "p d/,/ | s switch(comparenum(@level,0),1,'+','')+pad('-',@level-1)+id+':'+firstname+' '+lastname+'('+root(id)+':'+root(firstname)+' '+root(lastname)+')' | h k:id;p:managerid" samples/organization.csv
1:John A(1:John A)
+12:Winsor D(1:John A)
+-85:Jerry C(1:John A)
+--16:Smith H(1:John A)
+-108:Tom B(1:John A)
100:Ray G(100:Ray G)
+22:Albert B(100:Ray G)
+-21:Linda K(100:Ray G)
+-17:Robert J(100:Ray G)
+--35:Lily J(100:Ray G)
101:Sam A(101:Sam A)
+105:Liz Z(101:Sam A)
```